# how to fetch data from 2 different tables by comparing values of their fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables for products what I need to do is, get product's name and description on basis of their attributes i.e. If table1's product's attribute1 is same as table2's product attribute1 then fetch product name and description of both the table. I'm litile confused with query, can somebody please help.
Here is my query:

```
select Product_Article_Number, Product_Description, Comments, 
from P_Products as pp
WHERE EXISTS(select * from Competitor_Products as cc
WHERE(cc.CAttribute1 = pp.Attribute1 
     AND cc.CAttribute2 = pp.Attribute2 
     AND cc.CAttribute3 = pp.Attribute3 
     AND cc.CAttribute4 = pp.Attribute4))
```

result:
by this I'm getting details for table1 only, how to get other tables detail too.

Comment: `select pp.Product_Article_Number, pp.Product_Description, pp.Comments, cc.Product_Article_Number, cc.Product_Description, cc.Comments 
from P_Products as pp 
 join Competitor_Products as cc
on (cc.CAttribute1 = pp.Attribute1 
     AND cc.CAttribute2 = pp.Attribute2 
     AND cc.CAttribute3 = pp.Attribute3 
     AND cc.CAttribute4 = pp.Attribute4))`

Comment: use join query..

Comment: co comparing value like you said ALWAYS use join..try the code provided by splash it should work..

Comment: you will get data from both the tables..its a join query

Comment: refer this site ..you will get an idea..
http://www.dofactory.com/sql/join

Comment: Thank you so much everyone, but I need data representation in separate tables.